# Regex to check more than one condition in Android

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate the **EditText** value using **Regex**.
**The condition**:

1. User can enter unsigned integer
2. User can enter floating point value.

I have achieved this using two different Pattern but I have no idea to how to check both in single **Regex**.

I used this following Regex

```
public boolean validFloatForString(String value) {
        String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";
        String integerPattern = "([0-9]*)";
        boolean match = Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, value)
                || Pattern.matches(integerPattern, value);
        System.out.println(match); // if true then decimal else not
        return match;
    }
```

Comment: "regex" REGular EXpression. Why do you need one pattern? Can you use an optional marker on everything after ([0-9]*) ?

Comment: Edittext... seems like to be android. isn't it?

Comment: yes in android only @WEBALDO.at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)"` will match `.`, while `integerPattern` will always match. That's because `*` means 0 or more. 
I would use something like

```
String pattern = "^([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)";
```

Which matches unsigned integer and floats.

**Edit 1**

To match also unsigned floats, beginning with `.`

```
String pattern = "\\b([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)\\b";
```

I also substitute the `^`, which means beginning of the string to match, with word boundary `\\b`.

Comment: hi @davide its working fine but if suppose enter .xxx then it returns false

Comment: hi @davide its not working if i enter .(dot) means it return false pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android you could use the embedded validator for this and e.g. set the InputType:

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$`.

The above will make sure that the string is made up from one or more digits which is *optionally* followed by a decimal point and one or more digits.